# biblatex: how to get rid of abbreviate global option for a local \fullcite citation?

Tags: biblatex, citing, grouping

In the following MWE, I'd like the `\fullcite` citation (but not the bibliography) to be displayed as if `abbreviate=false` would be passed to `biblatex`. Is it possible to get rid of the `abbreviate` global option for a local `\fullcite` citation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber
  % ,abbreviate=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\fullcite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not quite clear for which part you want to deactivate abbreviate, but the key simply (re)defines a command and so switching is not difficult:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber
  ,abbreviate=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter\fullcite{companion}

\def\abx@str{abx@sstr}\fullcite{companion}

\def\abx@str{abx@lstr}\fullcite{companion}

\def\abx@str{abx@sstr}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was looking something like `blx@abbreviate` and certainly would have been missed `abx@sstr` and `abx@lstr`. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I simply searched for `abbreviate` in `biblatex2.sty`.